# Using Substitute or Replace to change specified characters to characters in another cell in a specific order Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, replace, office365, substitution

Imagine if you will that cell A1 has the following content: **Abba was a great band.**

Cell 2 is supposed to use Replace and/or Substitute to change the six occurrences of a to the replacements in cell 3

Cell 3 has the following: **123456**

So cell 2 should come up and look like: **1bb2 w3s 4 gre5t b6nd.**

So far I cannot find anything that allows me to do this. I have the potential for up to '19 of the a results' in a given cell. I figure I can do a 60 cell system using left to pull each character, check them, then use left on the replacement item to put it in sequence but that seems extremely burdensome

Comment: In the example you want to replace the first characters regardless of the case (`A,a`) with the corresponding numbers in cel3? is this the general case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Replace Occurrences of a Substring With a Sequence of Characters

- If the setup is always so convenient, you could use:

```
=LET(d,A1,s,C1,dl,"a",
TEXTJOIN(MID(s,SEQUENCE(,LEN(s)),1),0,TEXTSPLIT(d,dl,,,1)))
```

... which is short for (less readable than):

```
=LET(d,A1,s,C1,dl,"a",
   se,MID(s,SEQUENCE(,LEN(s)),1),
   sp,TEXTSPLIT(d,dl,,,1),
TEXTJOIN(se,0,sp))
```

- If you want to replace each substring (`"a"`) with an integer sequence, see the shortest formula in JvdV's answer.

Comment: =LET(d,A1,s,C1,dl,"a",se,MID(s,SEQUENCE(LEN(s)),1),sp,TEXTSPLIT(d,,dl,,1),TEXTJOIN(se,0,sp))

This is exactly the answer I needed, it works PERFECTLY!

Comment: Great answer. At risk of showing my age, just to note that if you choose case insensitive match in Textsplit you lose the upper case letters e.g. try 'The Animals were too back in the day' so for the general case you might want to include "a" and "A" as delimiters and not use the case insensitive option.

Comment: Thanks. That's a great point. I never looked too closely at `TEXTSPLIT`—quite a surprise. Your input is always welcome no matter how insignificant it may seem. Obviously, this is very significant.

Comment: It is a surprise - seems almost like a bug

Comment: I looked into it, and you're right it says *"Searches for a case-insensitive delimiter match"*. I thought I did something wrong. We are talking about the same thing here, that the `"The"` in your example gets converted to a `"the"`? Shared the issue with MS [here](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/dd8fe57d-43d1-ed11-a81b-6045bd808412). Is there a better place?

Comment: I have reported it a while ago through the feedback menu within Excel. You could also report it there.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently OP wishes to replace each occurence of "A" with the appropriate integer in sequence despite the content of cell 2. In fact cell 2 can just be discarded. One option:

[image]

If you want to replace it with the appropriate number:

```
=TEXTJOIN(SEQUENCE(,LEN(A1)),0,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"a",,,1))
```

Since, as commented, at time of writing `TEXTSPLIT()` bugs when we search for case-sensitive matches (it would return lowercase elements), we could also apply an array:

```
=TEXTJOIN(SEQUENCE(,LEN(A1)),0,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"a","A"}))
```

Comment: It appears I was not specific enough, I am actually using numbers only...  When I tried the first one, suggested on reddit, it used 0's first and then 1's....

Comment: @MichaelHarrington is the edit according to what you are after?

Comment: it is, but the solution is found, I am very happy with the results now.

Comment: Great. The last one made me remove my addition (*Who says the sequence can't be too long?*) and modify the remainder (it is more appropriate to split it into a row).

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008, took me a little while to figure out what OP was trying here though .

Comment: Nice. Try with 'The Animals were too back in the day' though and you may get a surprise.

Comment: Yeah I've seen and reported this behaviour before. Strange and stupid bug. @TomSharpe. We could for now counter this with an array of upper and lowercase "A".